# How do i move images from Mipmap to Drawables and retain their size in Android?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am just getting into an android project that someone else already worked on. I am currently just correcting UI issues and such, and we decided we needed bigger sizes of some graphics that look blurry on tablet size. So we decided to make a few size-dependent folders.
Until now, former guy has placed a lot of graphics into the mipmap folder because it automatically selects images based on density. But now i read that mipmap is only for the launcher icon. 
Now my dilemma is whether I should move the graphics or not. It wouldn't be too hard to do, but i tried with a few, and I noticed that when taken out of the mipmap folder, and placed inside the drawables folder, the graphics are suddenly bigger. This means that I either have to resize every single graphic, or replace the file with a smaller version.
I am tempted to leave well enough alone, and not invoke all sorts of re-design processes for the sake of keeping the structure tidy. But on the other hand, it kinda hurts not to.

Does anyone know what I should do, or if mipmap is ok to use for graphics that aren't the launcher icon? And if I am to move it, how do I best tackle all these problems?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html mipmap are only for your launcher icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would have larger images which are then used accordingly in the relevant drawable folders. Android takes care of resizing these automatically. This is also the reason why the images you have in the minimap folder are being enlarged when exported to the other folders.

If I were you, I would leave the graphic files in the same folder as the previous developer set them. Otherwise you will be getting pixelated images.

The other option would be to use an image-editing software to enlarge the images and copy them to their respective folders.

In the end it is up to you, but if as you are saying, there are many images, I would leave them where they are.

Answer (score 0):

mipmap is ok to use for graphic.in eclipse their are drawables folder to place images but in android studio project mipmap folders are default folder and you can put any type of images it will automatically adjust according to size but put 9paches image in that folder